# Div appears behind images of jquery.innerfade.js?

Tags: jquery, css, html, position

I am having an issue positioning a div that I've styled using CSS in front of an image slideshow created using the `innerfade.js` script found at http://medienfreunde.com/lab/innerfade/.

I have created an image rollover using a div, and using CSS to set a background image for it that changes to a second image on mouse over. However, when I try to position it over the `innerfade.js` slideshow, it goes behind it, not in front. I have the positioning for the div set to `absolute` and am using the `margin-top` and `margin-left` properties to position the div.

My question is this - How could I change my code so that the div containing the background images would be in front of the image slideshow?

I have my code for the button in a jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/Cwca22/SejUx/ - the `jquery.innerfade.js` script can be found from the website listed previously. (I'm using the 'portfolio' example included in the script's documentation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try applying a large `z-index` value to `.exploreButton`:

```
.exploreButton {
    background-image: url('http://f.cl.ly/items/0w082s253z2j1r3E3C3x/explore.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 216px;
    height: 52px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 9999;   // heres the trick
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you all for the tip - apparently I need to brush up more on my CSS. Z-index seemed to do the trick. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the z-index CSS property.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Answer (score 1):

Your jsfiddle doesn't have the slideshow you describe but it sounds like you just need to set the `z-index` of the `#exploreButton` element to something higher than that of the slideshow.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/z-index

Here's an example of using z-index: http://jsfiddle.net/SejUx/1/